# Is there a way to overload classes in a way similar to function overloading?

Tags: c++

We can overload functions by giving them a different number of parameters. For example, functions `someFunc()` and `someFunc(int i)` can do completely different things.

Is it possible to achieve the same effect on classes? For example, having one class name but creating one class if a function is not called and a different class if that function is not called. For example, If I have a `dataStorage` class, I want the internal implementation to be a list if only `add` is called, but want it to be a heap if both `add` and `pop` are called.

I am trying to implement this in C++, but I am curious if this is even possible. Examples in other languages would also help. Thanks!

Comment: `template`s come to mind. Also, your functions might always return a different data type... but as for the compiler to guess whether someone will only use `add` or both `add` and `pop`... nope, think of it: `pop` might be used in a different compilation unit, by which time your library should already be compiled.

Comment: You could have the data storage type as a template argument (template template type). `pop` will then be SFINAE.

Answer (score 0):

The type of an object must be completely known at the point of definition. The type cannot depend on what is done with the object later.

---

For the `dataStorage` example, you could define `dataStorage` as an abstract class. For example:

```cpp
struct dataStorage {
    virtual ~dataStorage() = default;
    virtual void add(dataType data) = 0;
    // And anything else necessarily common to all implementations.
};
```

There could be a "default" implementation that uses a list.

```cpp
struct dataList : public dataStorage {
    void add(dataType data) override;
    // And whatever else is needed.
};
```

There could be another implementation that uses a heap.

```cpp
struct dataHeap : public dataStorage {
    void add(dataType data) override;
    void pop(); // Maybe return `dataType`, if desired
    // And whatever else is needed.
};
```

Functions that need only to add data would work on references to `dataStorage`. Functions that need to pop data would work on references to `dataHeap`. When you define an object, you would choose `dataList` if the compiler allows it, `dataHeap` otherwise. (The compiler would not allow passing a `dataList` object to a function that requires a `dataHeap&`.) This is similar to what you asked for, except it does require manual intervention. On the bright side, you can use the compiler to tell you which decision to make.

A downside of this approach is that changes can get messy. There is additional maintenance and runtime overhead compared to simply always using a heap (one class, no inheritance). You should do some performance measurements to ensure that the cost is worth it. Sometimes simplicity is the best design, even if it is not optimal in all cases.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Can you also give me some information on why we need to know it by the point of definition? It seems like the compiler will have all the necessary information during compile time (since it is capable of giving me the error message). Is this related to some design decision?

Comment: *"Can you also give me some information on why we need to know it by the point of definition?"*--Not really. It's listed somewhere in the language specification, but if you want quotes from the standard, you should request that in the question (either explicitly or with the [tag:language-lawyer] tag). -- *"since [the compiler] is capable of giving me the error message"*--the ability of the compiler to produce the error message is dependent upon each function signature (manually) specifying whether it needs a `dataHeap&` or a `dataStorage&`. This would not happen if the types had the same name.

Comment: @David If it helps: It certainly would be possible to define a programming language (and a compiler for that language) with the feature you are looking for. That language would not be C++ though.